# To file something with something (party)?

Tags: prepositions

When you say
*You file your income tax return **with** ABC*,

What does the "with" mean? Against ABC or through ABC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you intend 'ABC' to mean!

If you are talking about putting a paper document in its proper place in a file (sorted alphabetically or by date), *with ABC* means 'in the ABC section of the file'.

If ABC is the tax office, *with* means 'in charge of' - you submit the tax return to them.

Comment: Yes, the second one is what I want to mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*File (noun) with* means that you have entered something as a legal document in charge of ABC.

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=file

> **2.** To enter (a legal document) as an official record.

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=with

> 5. In the charge or keeping of: left the cat with the neighbors.